Find the segment BT in the triangle inscribed below
In the figure, $AB.BC = 60$ and $BT.TP = 40$.
Calculate BT with B and T tangency points.
(Answer:$2\sqrt5$)

I try:
$AT.TC = BT.TP \implies AT.TC = 40$
$AM.AB = AT.AC$
$AT^2 = AM.AB \implies AT^2 = AT.AC$
$CN.CB = CT^2$
$\angle BPA \cong \angle BCA$

Please, like in your yesterday question, define how the figure is constructed : "being given a triangle ABC, we construct its circumcircle. Then we take the circle internaly tangent to this circle in $B$ and tangent to side $AC$ in a point called $T$", etc.

@JeanMarie The issue already comes with the drawing ready, it does not determine how it is built

Thanks for your answer. It is a pity (and non mathematicaly correct) that the definitions are not given to you "in extenso". In the future, attempt to write yourself for us a textual, progressive, definition.

@JeanMarie  Dispose...but these Peruvian problems are not easy to define as the figures are constructed and therefore the difficulty in solving them..
To be honest, I've never seen questions where the construct processes of the figures are defined.

Note first of all that chords $BM$ and $AB$ subtend the same angles in their respective circles, and the same holds for $BN$ and $BC$. Hence:
$$
{BM\over AB}={BN\over BC}={r\over R}
\quad\text{and}\quad
{AM\over AB}={CN\over BC}=1-{r\over R},
$$
where $r$ is the radius of circle $BMTN$ and $R$ is the radius of circle $BAPC$;
that is:
$$
{AM\over CN}={AB\over BC}.
$$
On the other hand:
$$
AM\cdot AB=AT^2
\quad\text{and}\quad
CN\cdot BC=CT^2
$$
that is:
$$
{AB^2\over BC^2}={AM\over CN}\cdot{AB\over BC}={AT^2\over CT^2}.
$$
It follows that:
$$
{AB\over BC}={AT\over CT}
$$
and $BT$ is then the bisector of $\angle ABC$. Moreover, from
$$
{AT\over AB}={CT\over BC}=k
$$
we get:
$$
k^2={AT\cdot CT\over AB\cdot BC}={40\over60}={2\over3}.
$$
The length of $BT$ can finally be computed from the known formula for the length of the angle bisector in a triangle:
$$
BT^2=AB\cdot BC\left(
1-{(AT+CT)^2\over(AB+BC)^2}
\right)=AB\cdot BC\left(
1-k^2
\right)=60\cdot{1\over3}=20.
$$


Excellent..thanks

I didn't understand well...could you explain better?"Note first of all that chords BM and AB.. same holds for BN and BC and why does this relationship guarantee the proportions?
.

Can I say that BT is diameter since they are points of tangency and therefore perpendicular to the center?

From $BM=2r\sin\alpha$ and $BA=2R\sin\alpha$ you get $BM/BA=r/R$. Angle $\alpha$ is formed by the tangent at $B$ with ray $BA$. The same reasoning (with a different angle) for $BN/BC=r/R$.

$BT$ is not a diameter, in general.

Would Angle $alpha$ be angle $ABP$? Are you  considering the triangles $BMT$ and $BAT$ right to use $BN=2rs in \alpha$ and $BA=2Rsin \alpha$?

If I have a straight line connecting two points of tangency on a circle, why wouldn't this straight line be the diameter?

Angle $\alpha$ is an inscribed angle insisting upon $BM$ or $AB$ in either circle: as I explained in my previous comment, those inscribed angles are both congruent to the angle formed by the common tangent at $$ with ray $M$. That $BM=2r\sin\alpha$ and so on follows from a theorem which is called "chord theorem" in Italy but apparently doesn't have a name in English. See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Relation_to_the_circumcircle

Point $T$ is a point of tangency with line $AC$, not with the other circle.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
